# Why doesn't gJip turn a paragraph into a line?

Tags: object-motions

Is there a good reason why `gJip` doesn't turn a paragraph into a line?

If not, how could I make it work that way?

Comment: because `gJ` is not an operator, that waits for a motion afterwards. You can however use `vipgJ` to join all lines in the current paragraph.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, `vipJ` worked as well.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I meant reason as distinct from cause.

Comment: Well, `vipJ` does something (slightly) different than `vipgJ`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, care to elaborate on the difference?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple: `gJip` doesn't work, because `gJ` is not an operator. See [:h operator](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#operator) for which operators exist. The easy workaround is to use visual mode, and then join all the lines, e.g. use `vipgJ`, because in visual mode `gJ` will join all those selected lines (see [:h v_gJ](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_gJ)).

If you want to know the reason, why `gJ` and also `J` has not been implemented as an operator, you have to ask Bill Joy (for `J` in original vi) and Bram Moolenaar (for `gJ` only available in Vim). My guess is, that using e.g. a motion for the join operation does not always make sense, e.g. the command `Jw` is non-sense.