# How to join lines within a block with `J`?

Tags: object-motions, join

I want to join all the lines within a `{}` block.

```
{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
}
```

⬇︎

```
{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, }
```

Since `J` doesn't take a range, like `d` or `c`, the best command I found to do this is going through virtual mode: `Va{J`.

Is there a nicer way to do the same?

---

This is not a duplicated of [Why doesn't gJip turn a paragraph into a line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21674/why-doesnt-gjip-turn-a-paragraph-into-a-line) since that question doesn't ask *how* to turn a paragraph into a line. The proper answer of that question is "`gJ` doesn't work like that".

Comment: `J` takes a count...that's not what you're looking for? Note that `d` and `c` don't take ranges. They take motions (including count). Do you mean motion rather than range? (there's also `:join` which takes a range and/or a count so if you `nmap` that it might work for you.)

Comment: Rephrasing the first question, is `5J` from the opening `{`` not to your liking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't gJip turn a paragraph into a line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21674/why-doesnt-gjip-turn-a-paragraph-into-a-line)

Comment: @BLayer The ranges I have aren't always 5 lines long.

Comment: Of course not. That was the solution to your example. You need to know the count. You didn't give enough information to determine whether `[count]J` was acceptable so I asked.

Answer (score 5):

This is called "a motion". Even though linewise motions result in a line range.

Normally, it's enough to do `5J` and there's no need for "join" operator. However, if you really want it, you can make use of `:h g@` and `:h 'opfunc'` A simplified example:

```
" very basic "join" operator
nnoremap <silent>J :set opfunc=OperJoin<CR>g@
function! OperJoin(type) abort
    '[,']join
endfunction
```

Now `Ja{` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since `J` works in visual mode...

```
va{J
```

More generally `v[motion or text object]J`. Normally I would say this is a bit of an anti-pattern (prefer `[operator][motion or text object]`), but there is no join operator.

Here, even `v%J` should work

---

Alternately, use `:join`, which takes a range, and ranges can be quite powerful:

```
.,/}/join
```

Comment: Thanks for this most useful suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The commandline command you're looking for is 'j':

```
:1,5j
```

Comment: I can't so this within an arbitrary `{}` block though.